# How to make visible an HTML element using variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get a part of the of the btn ID, and then to combine it with another string,
and together it's the name of an hidden element which I'm trying to make visible. And I got this error:

> `string` does not contain a definition for `Visible` and no extension method `Visible` accepting a first argument of type `string` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnAddAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    string id = btn.ID;
    string[] array = id.Split('r');
    string Name = "rowAnswer" + array[1];
    Name.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do just `Name.Visible` you will have to do a `Control.FindControl`. Somthing like this

```
  // Find control on page.
  Control myControl1 = FindControl(Name);
  if(myControl1!=null)
  {
     Control myControl1.Visible = true;
  }
```

Also note that the control must be a server control (tagged `runat = "server"`)

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y81z8326%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)